# Thanking visitor by name after contact form submision

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm a web development student and I'm trying to find a way to thank a visitor who submits a contact form from my website.  I want to thank them by name on a thank you page. Below is the code of my form. please help a student learn.

```
<form action="http://www.MySiteUrl/cgi-sys/formmail.pl" method="post" enctype="plain/text" id="Contact">  
            <input name="Name" type="text" class="quoteboxes" id="Name" />

        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Name is required.</span></span></div>
    <!-- End InputFavSite -->
     <div id="inputneed">
         <label>Email </label><span id="sprytextfield6">
         <input name="Email" type="text" class="quoteboxes" id="Email" />
         <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">E-mail is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Opse! your E-mail is wrong.</span></span></div>
     <!-- End InputNeed -->
      <div id="inputbudjet"> <label>Phone </label><span id="sprytextfield7">
      <input name="Phone" type="text" class="quoteboxes" id="Phone" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Phone is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Opse! your number is wrong..</span></span></div>
      <!-- End InputBudget -->
       <div id="inputtime">
           <label>Subject </label>      <span id="sprytextfield8">

               <input name="Subject" type="text" class="quoteboxes" id="Subject" />

           <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Subject is required.</span></span></div>
       <!-- End InputTime -->
     <div id="ccontact"><span id="sprytextarea">
         <textarea name="Message" class="quotemessase" id="Message"></textarea>
         <span class="textareaRequiredMsg">Message is required.</span></span></div><!-- End QuoteButtRight -->
         <div id="contactbttn">
           <input name="sender" type="submit" value="click to send your message" />
         </div><!-- End ContactBttn -->

    </div><!-- End QuoteTopRight-->


    </div><!-- End QuoteTop -->

           <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="info@siteripe.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="yourURL/Thankspage" />

    </form>
```

Comment: You will need to use a server-side language for this. Which language are you using?

Comment: Align, tab, structure and write helpful comment in your code base will help you learn programming.

Comment: Well, I recommend learning about PHP. Search for tutorials that walk you through building a basic HTML form (such as yours) and then for another tutorial that teaches you how to build the form submission script in PHP. But, I think for your current project, just go with the JavaScript solutions that other users have mentioned below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As adviced I used a PHP Form mailer, killed the line of Code that re-directs and then used

#### `<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>,`

to collect and display the name of the visitor on the thank you page

Answer (score 2):

you can save the name value into a cookie before form is submitted (using javascript), and then fetch it from the cookie using javascript.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

or use a server side language (php etc)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a cheap javascript version (no server-side code), you can do something like the following:

1. On submit of the form, append `?name={name here}` to `redirect` variable.
2. On `thanks.html`, read the querystring variable and put on screen to user.

Comment: Mella please tell me, how exactly should I do that?