# Php <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?> Usage

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thanking visitor by name after contact form submision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656428/thanking-visitor-by-name-after-contact-form-submision)

I have the line of codes below on my "Thank you page"

```
<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?> Thanks for contacting us
```

And I want it to get the name value from the form below but when the form is sent, it only shows "Thanks for contacting us" without the visitors name.

```
<form action="http://www.siteripe.com/cgi-sys/formmail.pl" method="post" enctype="plain/text" id="Contact"> 

<div id="inputfavsite">
    <label>Name</label> <span id="name">

        <input name="Name" type="text" class="quoteboxes" id="Name" />

    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Name is required.</span></span></div>
<!-- End InputFavSite -->
 <div id="inputneed">
     <label>Email </label><span id="sprytextfield6">
     <input name="from" type="text" class="quoteboxes" id="from" />
     <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">E-mail is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Opse! your E-mail is wrong.</span></span></div>
 <!-- End InputNeed -->
  <div id="inputbudjet"> <label>Phone </label><span id="sprytextfield7">
  <input name="Phone" type="text" class="quoteboxes" id="Phone" />
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Phone is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Opse! your number is wrong..</span></span></div>
  <!-- End InputBudget -->
   <div id="inputtime">
       <label>Subject </label>      <span id="sprytextfield8">

           <input name="Subject" type="text" class="quoteboxes" id="Subject" />

       <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Subject is required.</span></span></div>
   <!-- End InputTime -->
 <div id="ccontact"><span id="sprytextarea">
     <textarea name="Message" class="quotemessase" id="Message"></textarea>
     <span class="textareaRequiredMsg">Message is required.</span></span></div><!-- End QuoteButtRight -->
     <div id="contactbttn">
       <input name="sender" type="submit" value="click to send your message" />
     </div><!-- End ContactBttn -->

</div><!-- End QuoteTopRight-->


</div><!-- End QuoteTop -->

       <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="info@siteripe.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.siteripe.com/thanks.php" />

</form>
```

Please help me learn.

Comment: You must post your form before we can help you

Comment: Read the site's FAQ and learn how to use code blocks correctly. I edited your post to make your code show up.

Comment: Also, the problem is you are submitting the form to `http://www.siteripe.com/cgi-sys/formmail.pl`. This is a standard perl script and has nothing to do with your PHP code. Please explain how you are accessing your php page and how you expect the form to connect to it.

Comment: Are you sure your are talking about PHP? Your are sending your form to an Perl Script propably. I mean: http://www.siteripe.com/cgi-sys/formmail.pl

Comment: Thank Ben. It actually Sends the mail but I'd like the thank you page to thank the visors by their name.

Comment: @Dz.slick, see my answer for a more detailed explanation of what I mean.

Comment: Also, just realized you already posted this question...

Comment: I think you are at the wrong site for your answer. Instead, please read a basic tutorial about how PHP works. You clearly are not understanding some basic fundamentals of how the process works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (or at least one of the problems) is that your code is submitting the form to `http://www.siteripe.com/cgi-sys/formmail.pl`. This is a standard perl script and has nothing to do with your PHP code.

Please explain how you are accessing your php page and how you expect the form to connect to it.

One possibility is to change this line:

```
<form action="http://www.siteripe.com/cgi-sys/formmail.pl" ...>
```

To this:

```
<form action="http://www.yourdomain.com/yourscript.php" ...>
```

But then you also have to update the PHP code to send an email based on the form contents. That is beyond the scope of this answer, but you can see complete docs and examples for how to send email in php here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Ben, I don't have PHP form mailer. I'm using Hostgator's default formmailer.

Comment: Thanks Ben I sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: And the problem itself *is* that you are using a script on an external site that is not even written in PHP. If you want a thank you page you *must* implement it yourself (or include the code from a third-party *PHP* script onto your site).

Comment: I had to use a PHP form mailer like you advised.

Answer (score 3):

You have to echo `$_POST["Name"]` and not `$_POST["name"]`.

Comment: Standardize or else stuff like this happens.

Comment: Agreed, consistency is crucial.

Comment: And not just in variable names. Be consistent with your whitespace and indentation patterns too. Your code is a mess and extremely hard to read because you have no consistent indentation style.

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST["name"]` and `$_POST["Name"]` are different. You have "Name" in your form but "name" in your code.